# Can't reset a JS timer in a one state app (ajax page loads)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am having an issue with reseting a JS timer in a one state app that uses ajax to load new pages, so the page rarely experiences a full reload. The timer is used to countdown the date on inquiry pages (similar concept to ebay) and there are multiple inquiry pages - all with different timers and expiry dates.

The timer works perfectly on a full page reload, but after that, it gets increasingly faster and starts storing all the different timers simultaneously (e.g. if I visited three inquiry pages and initialized three timers, now its gonna count 3 seconds per second instead of 1.)

Here is my timer function

```
var timer = {
    isActive : null,
    firstLoad : null,
    currentTime: null,
    distance : null,
    duration : null,

    init: function() {
        var scope = timer;

        if (scope.isActive) {

            scope.counter();

        }
        else {
            $("#countdown").html("-");
        }

    },

    counter: function() {
        var scope = timer;

        scope.countdown = setInterval(function() {

            if (scope.firstLoad) {
                scope.distance = scope.activeTo - scope.currentTime;
                scope.duration = moment.duration(scope.distance);

                scope.firstLoad = false;
            }
            else {
                scope.duration.subtract(1, "second");
            }


            // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
            var days = scope.duration.days();
            var hours = scope.duration.hours();
            if (hours < 10) {
                hours = "0" + hours;
            }
            var minutes = scope.duration.minutes();
            if (minutes < 10) {
                minutes = "0" + minutes;
            }
            var seconds = scope.duration.seconds();
            if (seconds < 10) {
                seconds = "0" + seconds;
            }

            // Display the result in the element with id="countdown"
            jQuery("#countdown").html(days + "&nbsp;<%= pdo.translate("countdown.days.label")%>&nbsp;" + hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds);


            // If the count down is finished, write some text
            if (scope.distance < 0) {
                $("#addNewBid, #cancelInquiry, #editInquiry").hide();
                $("#countdown").html("<%= pdo.translate("countdown.timeend.label")%>");
            }
        }, 1000);

    },

    reset: function() {
        var scope = timer;

        clearInterval(scope.countdown);

        scope.isActive = null;
        scope.firstLoad = null;
        scope.currentTime = null;
        scope.distance = null;
        scope.duration = null;

    }
};
```

And this is how I reset and initialize it on new page load.

```
$(document).ready(function ($) {


    timer.reset();

    timer.currentTime = new moment("<%=pdo.getTime()%>");
    timer.activeTo = new moment("<%= pdo.getInquiry().getActiveTo() %>");
    timer.isActive = <%=pdo.getInquiry().isActive()%>;
    timer.firstLoad = true;

    timer.init();
});
```